# web content slider with fixed menu bar on the left side

Tags: jquery, html

Hi there I am trying to create a slide content page, that has a fixed menu on the left side and sliding content in the middle. I am using twitter bootstrap and in there I am trying to put the menu inside the  class. right now everything its all over the place and I dont know how to get the content in the center and menu fixed on the left side so only stuff in the middle moves.

here is the code , any help is much appreciated 
http://jsfiddle.net/4HBmV/

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div class="well sidebar-nav">


    <div id="mask">

    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
          <div class="well sidebar-nav">
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
              <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><div id="item1" class="item">
             <a href="#item2" class="panel">1</a>       

        </li>

            </ul>
          </div><!--/.well -->
        </div><!--/span-->
</div>
```

and here is the actual jquery slider http://www.queness.com/resources/html/scroll/vertical.html